# Deploying / Creating Analysis Services Database using an ASSL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap

Im trying to deploy as Analysis Services database using an ASSL script.

I can create the script using "script as" in management studio. But I can't find out how to run this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in management studio, new XMLA query does the job.